# Pandas FloatingPoint Error

Tags: python, ipython, pandas

I'm getting a floating point error on a simple time series in pandas.  I'm trying to do shift operations... but this also happens with the window functions like *`rolling_mean`*.

EDIT: For some more info... I tried to actually build this from source yesterday prior to the error.  I'm not sure if the error would've occurred prior the build attempt, as I'd never messed around w/ these functions.

EDIT2: I thought I'd fixed this, but when I run this inside python it works, but when it's in ipython I get the error.

EDIT3: Numpy 1.7.0, iPython 0.13, pandas 0.7.3

```
In [35]: ts = Series(np.arange(12), index=DateRange('1/1/2000', periods=12, freq='T'))

In [36]: ts.shift(0)
Out[36]: 
2000-01-03     0
2000-01-04     1
2000-01-05     2
2000-01-06     3
2000-01-07     4
2000-01-10     5
2000-01-11     6
2000-01-12     7
2000-01-13     8
2000-01-14     9
2000-01-17    10
2000-01-18    11

In [37]: ts.shift(1)
Out[37]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FloatingPointError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/trenthauck/Repository/work/SQS/analysis/campaign/tv2/data/<ipython-input-37-2b7cec97d440> in <module>()
----> 1 ts.shift(1)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13.dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/displayhook.pyc in __call__(self, result)
    236             self.start_displayhook()
    237             self.write_output_prompt()
--> 238             format_dict = self.compute_format_data(result)
    239             self.write_format_data(format_dict)
    240             self.update_user_ns(result)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13.dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/displayhook.pyc in compute_format_data(self, result)
    148             MIME type representation of the object.
    149         """
--> 150         return self.shell.display_formatter.format(result)
    151 
    152     def write_format_data(self, format_dict):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13.dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in format(self, obj, include, exclude)
    124                     continue
    125             try:
--> 126                 data = formatter(obj)
    127             except:
    128                 # FIXME: log the exception

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13.dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj)
    445                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    446                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 447             printer.pretty(obj)
    448             printer.flush()
    449             return stream.getvalue()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13.dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in pretty(self, obj)
    353                 if callable(obj_class._repr_pretty_):
    354                     return obj_class._repr_pretty_(obj, self, cycle)
--> 355             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    356         finally:
    357             self.end_group()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13.dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in _default_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    473     if getattr(klass, '__repr__', None) not in _baseclass_reprs:
    474         # A user-provided repr.
--> 475         p.text(repr(obj))
    476         return
    477     p.begin_group(1, '<')

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __repr__(self)
    696             result = self._get_repr(print_header=True,
    697                                     length=len(self) > 50,
--> 698                                     name=True)
    699         else:
    700             result = '%s' % ndarray.__repr__(self)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in _get_repr(self, name, print_header, length, na_rep, float_format)
    756                                         length=length, na_rep=na_rep,
    757                                         float_format=float_format)
--> 758         return formatter.to_string()
    759 
    760     def __str__(self):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in to_string(self)
     99 
    100         fmt_index, have_header = self._get_formatted_index()
--> 101         fmt_values = self._get_formatted_values()
    102 
    103         maxlen = max(len(x) for x in fmt_index)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in _get_formatted_values(self)
     90         return format_array(self.series.values, None,
     91                             float_format=self.float_format,
---> 92                             na_rep=self.na_rep)
     93 
     94     def to_string(self):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in format_array(values, formatter, float_format, na_rep, digits, space, justify)
    431                         justify=justify)
    432 
--> 433     return fmt_obj.get_result()
    434 
    435 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in get_result(self)
    528 
    529             # this is pretty arbitrary for now
--> 530             has_large_values = (np.abs(self.values) > 1e8).any()
    531 
    532             if too_long and has_large_values:

FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in absolute

In [38]: ts.shift(-1)
Out[38]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FloatingPointError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/myusername/Repository/work/SQS/analysis/campaign/tv2/data/<ipython-input-38-314ec815a7c5> in <module>()
----> 1 ts.shift(-1)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13.dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/displayhook.pyc in __call__(self, result)
    236             self.start_displayhook()
    237             self.write_output_prompt()
--> 238             format_dict = self.compute_format_data(result)
    239             self.write_format_data(format_dict)
    240             self.update_user_ns(result)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13.dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/displayhook.pyc in compute_format_data(self, result)
    148             MIME type representation of the object.
    149         """
--> 150         return self.shell.display_formatter.format(result)
    151 
    152     def write_format_data(self, format_dict):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13.dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in format(self, obj, include, exclude)
    124                     continue
    125             try:
--> 126                 data = formatter(obj)
    127             except:
    128                 # FIXME: log the exception

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13.dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/formatters.pyc in __call__(self, obj)
    445                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    446                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 447             printer.pretty(obj)
    448             printer.flush()
    449             return stream.getvalue()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13.dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in pretty(self, obj)
    353                 if callable(obj_class._repr_pretty_):
    354                     return obj_class._repr_pretty_(obj, self, cycle)
--> 355             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    356         finally:
    357             self.end_group()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13.dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/lib/pretty.pyc in _default_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    473     if getattr(klass, '__repr__', None) not in _baseclass_reprs:
    474         # A user-provided repr.
--> 475         p.text(repr(obj))
    476         return
    477     p.begin_group(1, '<')

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in __repr__(self)
    696             result = self._get_repr(print_header=True,
    697                                     length=len(self) > 50,
--> 698                                     name=True)
    699         else:
    700             result = '%s' % ndarray.__repr__(self)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in _get_repr(self, name, print_header, length, na_rep, float_format)
    756                                         length=length, na_rep=na_rep,
    757                                         float_format=float_format)
--> 758         return formatter.to_string()
    759 
    760     def __str__(self):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in to_string(self)
     99 
    100         fmt_index, have_header = self._get_formatted_index()
--> 101         fmt_values = self._get_formatted_values()
    102 
    103         maxlen = max(len(x) for x in fmt_index)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in _get_formatted_values(self)
     90         return format_array(self.series.values, None,
     91                             float_format=self.float_format,
---> 92                             na_rep=self.na_rep)
     93 
     94     def to_string(self):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in format_array(values, formatter, float_format, na_rep, digits, space, justify)
    431                         justify=justify)
    432 
--> 433     return fmt_obj.get_result()
    434 
    435 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.pyc in get_result(self)
    528 
    529             # this is pretty arbitrary for now
--> 530             has_large_values = (np.abs(self.values) > 1e8).any()
    531 
    532             if too_long and has_large_values:

FloatingPointError: invalid value encountered in absolute
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Python 2.7.3, pandas 0.7.0

Comment: Thanks - are did you try this in ipython or python?

Comment: 1.7.0, installed using the scipysuperpack

PS, just bought your Python for Data Analysis early release, which is great, but also how I ran into this.

Comment: Yes, I tried with ipython without any problems. Though mine was 0.12.1. You are using a development version, both for ipython and numpy. It's highly possible that those are unstable. That might be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add this as a comment, but I don't have the privilege to do that yet :)

It works for me in python and iPython 0.12; iPython 0.13 is still in development (see http://ipython.org/ ), and, since the errors you're getting seem to involve formatting in the iPython 0.13 egg, I suspect that might be the cause. Try with iPython 0.12 instead-- if it works, file a bug report with iPython and then probably stick with 0.12 until 0.13 is (more) stable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm still getting the error on 0.12.  So it seems to be more pervasive in my system.  Oddly works in bpython.

Comment: Hm. Just a stab, but, what happens if you try np.abs([np.nan, 1, 2, 3]) in iPython?

Comment: Thought so. Are you sure your iPython numpy is the same as the other installs? Try np.__version__ in the working vs. nonworking environments.

Comment: It is the same version `1.7.0.dev-3cb783e`.

Comment: I'm guessing your iPython for some reason is operating with a lower error threshold. The FloatingPointError about the NaN raises an "invalid" flag which is usually ignored, but can be raised if desired. Check out the docs here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/misc.html#how-numpy-handles-numerical-exceptions , and play around with resetting the numpy errors as in the examples. Does that fix it? If so, there must be some way to configure the error levels for iPython...

Comment: I've solved this... even though the version numbers were some build issues I guess.  I cleaned up the packages I had and it works now... thanks for all them help.